# How do I use new add_editor_style() function in wordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, twenty-ten-theme

I found this article:

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/editor-style-wordpress-30.html

I created a child theme using the Twentyten theme as a parent. I am trying to have the WYSIWYG editor use a custom stylesheet.

I added this to my functions.php file:

```
add_editor_style();
```

Then I created an **editor-style.css** file in my child theme's folder and added this:

```
html .mceContentBody {
    max-width:591px;
}
```

When I go to the WYSIWYG editor and use firebug to check the css that is affecting the **.mceContentBody** element, I can see that is using my stylesheet, but it is being overrriden by the default editor-style.css sheet from the twentyten theme.

How can I force it to use my editor-style.css file and not the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add_theme_support('editor_style');

before

```
add_editor_style('tinymce-styles.css');
```

assuming that your custom css is in your template's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try redeclaring `twentyten_setup` in your theme's functions.php file. Just copy and paste the whole function from twentyten to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS for errors. I spent hours pulling my hair out wondering why wordpress wasn't using my stylesheet. It wasn't even getting included. Turns out i had an extra { in my css.