# Wordpress Admin: Adding css styles to Rich text editor drop down

Tags: wordpress, rich-text-editor

Hey does anyone know how to add your own custom css classes to the Wordpress admin rich text editor drop downs?

When editing a post you see the drop downs to format the selected text to be a paragraph, address or h3 tag.  What would be the proper way to add an option "Highlight" that would change the selected text from:

`selected text`

to:

```
<span class="highlight">selected text</span>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using WP3, try using the following function in your theme's functions.php file:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

More detailed instructions:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-new-add_editor_style-function

Related SO question:
[How do I use new add_editor_style() function in wordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490774/how-do-i-use-new-add-editor-style-function-in-wordpress)